# How to make "global" variable available in Laravel helper and view?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-blade, server-side-rendering

I'm working on a Laravel app that I'm transitioning to React using a microfrontend(-like?) approach. I defined a helper function in Laravel that receives a component name and array of props and outputs the server-side rendered React HTML. I then call this function inside my views where needed.

Each page in my application defines a few variables that might affect the rendering both of these React components and also the Blade templates. So I define the variables in the view and send them to JavaScript land through a global `window` variable. But I also need these variables in the SSR helper.

Right now I have two ideas on how to do this:

1. Pass the variables as props in each call to my helper function. I want to avoid this as the variables will never change throughout the request lifecycle and all the @includes and @extends
2. Set the values using `config` helper before rendering the view. This seems kind of unidiomatic, as I think `config` should be used with more "static" values (that apply for the whole application and not particular pages), but I'm not very well versed in Laravel-world so this might actually be acceptable.

So right now I'm more inclined to 2, but I was wondering if there was a better option?

**Some code:**

my-template.blade.php

```php
//these are the variables that I want to access in my helper
@extends('master.index', [
  "_PAGE_CONFIG" => [
    "page" => "blog",
    "header" => ["search" => true]
  ]
]);

@section('content')

@include('some-template.that-also-has.ssr-components-in-it')

{!! ssr('blog/Blog', ["posts" => $posts]) !!}

@endsection
```

master/index.blade.php

```php
<body>

@if($_PAGE_CONFIG["header"])
<header>{!! ssr('header/Header') !!}</header>
@endif

@yield('content')

<script>
//here I pass my variables to (client) JS land
window._PAGE_CONFIG = @json($_PAGE_CONFIG);
</script>

</body>
```

my-SSR-helper.php

```php
function ssr($component, $props = []) {
  /*
  here I call a node server or script that handles the rendering for me,
  but I want to pass it $_PAGE_CONFIG, which will be different in each page.
  I could pass it in each ssr call in the template but this is what I want to avoid
  as this function might be called several times down the @include/@extend chain
  and $_PAGE_CONFIG never changes in any one page
  (but might be different for different pages).
  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If each page always gets the same values, then you should set an array somewhere into your config where the keys are the pages and the values are the props received. By the way, you would get:

```php
function ssr($component, $page, $props = []) {
  $pageProps = config('somewhere.'.$page);
}
```

Comment: I don't need to make a global common value available to all views, I need to make a value from the views available globally.

Comment: I'm not used to SSR, may you please post some code sample to understand your context? If you build your JS files, you may use Laravel mix to inject some environment variables.

Comment: added some minimal examples to the original post

Comment: Ok, about these variables, are they dynamic on the same page or 1 page gets the same values everytime?

Comment: Each page has the same values everytime, they only differ between pages

Comment: Is it too bad to set the config at the top of each page like `config(["PAGE_CONFIG" => etc])` and then access it inside ssr function `config("PAGE_CONFIG")` without having to know what page i'm in?

Comment: Why do you want to set some config if it's constant?

Comment: I suppose you're right, what I think I want is to keep stuff that belongs to the page/view self-contained instead of being defined in some other file, which I guess is probably not the Laravel (or other similar frameworks) way

Comment: I understand your way, and you can set some config at runtime if you want to keep your data at the same location. I also do that to add database connections dynamically (except I do not have choice unlike you)

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to see people using micro-frontends to use React to server-side rendering in a non-javascript framework like Laravel.

I recommend you take a look at this article [Universal Rendering in Laravel using Vue.js and Ara Framework](https://dev.to/phillipgd1992/universal-rendering-in-laravel-using-vue-js-and-ara-framework-5amd). Ara Framework supports also React, I think the server-side include approach is the best option to overcome the limitations of Blade.

This article can give you context about how this approach works.
https://itnext.io/strangling-a-monolith-to-micro-frontends-decoupling-presentation-layer-18a33ddf591b